# Python Web-scraping. How to fix sorting by the date a post was made public

Tags: python, sorting, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is script is writing for web scraping news from Thehackernews website.
The main goal :

- Send the mail with only links (href) which contain special Strings (In the Class Scraper presented and sort by the Table. 75 line of code)
- Redis database only in localhost. Not to save much data to the database. Light and fast work.
- Send email everyday from schedule with links.

But when I tested the script and add more special string into the table. The request is repeat , because is not sorted by the date etc.

In html code from thehackernews website the date is presented  like this :

- `<span class='h-datetime'><i class='icon-font icon-calendar'>&#59394;</i>Dec 22, 2022</span>`

My code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import redis
from password import bot_email_pw
import requests


# source
# source
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, keywords):
        self.markup = requests.get('https://thehackernews.com/').text
        self.keywords = keywords

    # parser
    def parse(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.markup, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.findAll('a')
        """links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "titlelink"})"""
        self.saved_links = []
        for link in links:
            for keyword in self.keywords:
                if keyword in link.text:
                    self.saved_links.append(link)

    # store
    def store(self):
        r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
        for link in self.saved_links:
            """r.set(link.get('href'), link.h2.text)"""
            r.set(link.text,link.get('href'))
            print(link)

#send email

    def email(self):
        r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
        links = [str(r.get(k)) for k in r.keys()]
        print(links)

        # email
        import smtplib
        from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.mime.text import MIMEText

        fromEmail = ""
        toEmail = ""

        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "Newsy z HackerNews"
        msg['From'] = fromEmail
        msg['To'] =toEmail

        html = """
            <h4> %s linków mogących ciebie zainteresować: </h4>
            %s <br/></br> 
         """% (len(links), "<br/> <br/>".join(links))

        mime = MIMEText(html,'html')
        msg.attach(mime)

        try:
            mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            mail.ehlo()
            mail.starttls()
            mail.login(fromEmail, "")
            mail.sendmail(fromEmail, toEmail.split(','), msg.as_string())
            mail.quit()
            print(('Email sent!'))
        except Exception as exc:
            print('something might went wrong...%s' % exc)

        # Free redis
        r.flushdb()


s = Scraper(['malware','exploit','cve','ransomware','campaign','agent tesla','Hackers','hackers','hacker','Hacker','Ddos',
             'Vulnerability','vulnerability','Botnet','Dec 20'])
s.parse()
s.store()
s.email()
```

`

**The questions is how to sorting** this html code (which is scraping by  BeautifulSoup) by date post on the website. And only send me the this links, which is real public for example on 22.12

Answer (score 0):

Just filter on the post date and if it matches today's date then check if the keyword is in the link.

You can easily adapt the code to your needs and push the relevant links to the DB.

For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, keywords):
        self.saved_links = None
        self.markup = requests.get('https://thehackernews.com/').text
        self.keywords = keywords

    def parse(self):
        posts = BeautifulSoup(self.markup, 'html.parser').select(".body-post")
        self.saved_links = []
        for post in posts:
            date = (
                post
                .select_one('span[class="h-datetime"]')
                .getText(strip=True)
                .replace("", "")
            )
            if date == datetime.now().strftime("%b %d, %Y"):
                if any(word in post.text for word in self.keywords):
                    self.saved_links.append(post.select_one('a').attrs['href'])
        return self.saved_links


s = Scraper(
    [
        'malware', 'exploit', 'cve', 'ransomware', 'campaign', 'agent tesla',
        'Hackers', 'hackers', 'hacker', 'Hacker', 'Ddos', 'Vulnerability',
        'vulnerability', 'Botnet', 'Dec 20',
    ]
)
print("\n".join(s.parse()))
```

This prints:

```
https://thehackernews.com/2022/12/two-new-security-flaws-reported-in.html
https://thehackernews.com/2022/12/zerobot-botnet-emerges-as-growing.html
https://thehackernews.com/2022/12/hackers-breach-oktas-github.html
```